# How do I compile a 64-bit version of ffmpeg on Windows?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, ffmpeg, mingw

i need to compile ffmpeg (64 bit shared dll) for windows.
however I configure in mingw, it always produces 32 bit binary for me.

tried this already

```
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-memalign-hack --arch=amd64
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-memalign-hack --arch=x86_64
```

my guess is that a x86 to x86_64 cross compiler is missing.

but just can find a way to make those 64bit dlls.

Comment: How is compiling something not programming related?

Comment: It is. This question should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) for a 64-bit version of MinGW. The site even has 64-bit binaries of the ffmpeg library!

**UPDATE:** Meanwhile it's easier to build on/for Windows, e.g. through [ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers) scripts.

Comment: I cannot reach the linked page. Has it moved?

Comment: Seems the site has vanished. Now linking to a maintained project (which also includes prebuilt ffmpeg).